# Sending Data between two objects not working

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview

I am currently trying to pass data from a `UICollectionViewCell` in one Viewcontroller to another called `GameLobbyViewController`.

**ViewController.swift**

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let gameLobbyViewController: GameLobbyViewController = GameLobbyViewController()
        gameLobbyViewController.lobbyModelObject = lobbyGames[indexPath.row]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gameLobbyViewController, animated: true)
    }
```

**GameLobbyViewController**

```
class GameLobbyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var lobbyModelObject: LobbyGameModel!
```

When I went through the debugger, when I stop at this line of code: 
`gameLobbyViewController.lobbyModelObject = lobbyGames[indexPath.row]`

it shows that the value is set to this object but when I click the cell it says that lobbyModelObject is `nil`. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

I can print all the fields for the lobbyObjectModel passed, but when I assign UILabels to the value of the lobbyModelObject,  `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` is thrown at me.

Comment: Is `self.navigationController?` non-nil when you attempt the push?  (Not sure what you mean by "when I click the cell".)

Comment: It is non-nil and its' inside of the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` delegate method

Comment: show a bit more code.

Comment: is GameLobbyViewController setup int he storyboard? If that's true, check if you have 2 instances of it?